# sed - how to replace yaml.j2 nested value

Tags: bash, sed, yaml

I have a command that I use to replace **myid** value but its not perfect. Here is document where the issue occurs:

```
brand:
    group1:
        jerry:
            myid: 1
        ben:
            myid: 2
    group2:
        jerry:
            myid: 3
        jane:
            myid: 4
```

I am using **sed** to replace **myid**. I can lookup ids and names, but not groups

`sed -i -E "/jerry:/,/myid:/ s|(myid:).*|\1 NEWID|; " PATH_TO_FILE.yaml.j2`

issue 1: this will replace both jerrys ids. I want to replace jerry ONLY in group 1

issue 2: this will replace anything that has jerry inside its name, even

```
group1:
    jamesjerry:
        myid: 5
```

this is command I tried to filter by group to resolve issue number 1

`sed -i -E "/group1:/,/jerry:/,/myid:/ s|(myid:).*|\1 NEWID|; " PATH_TO_FILE.yaml.j2`

but then I get error:

`sed: 1: "/group1:/,jerry ...": invalid command code ,`

How could I use sed to replace value by filtering 3 different values in sed and ensure to filter only exact name? (Group1 -> Jerry -> myid)

Comment: What do you hope `/group1:/,/jerry:/,/myid:/` ought to mean? This is not a valid addressing expression. Which lines do you hope for it to match (and why did you imagine this was the way)?

Answer (score 3):

Trying to alter structured data like YAML with a text-processing tool like sed has its limits. For every solution there will be another valid input document for which it can fail.

Rather consider using a command-line YAML parser like [kislyuk/yq](https://www.github.com/kislyuk/yq) or [mikefarah/yq](https://www.github.com/mikefarah/yq) or [itchyny/gojq](https://www.github.com/itchyny/gojq). With all of them (for kislyuk/yq, add the `-y` flag; for itchyny/gojq, replace `yq` with `gojq --yaml-input --yaml-output`) you could simply address the exact position to change using:

```bash
yq '.brand.group1.jerry.myid = 5' file.yaml
```

```yaml
brand:
  group1:
    jerry:
      myid: 5
    ben:
      myid: 2
  group2:
    jerry:
      myid: 3
    jane:
      myid: 4
```

Note: For all tools mentioned, you can add the `-i` flag to modify the input file in-place (instead of just outputting the result to STDOUT).

Comment: OP explicitly asks for sed.

Comment: yq doesn't work with yaml.j2 (templating)

Comment: @rkochar I know, but I felt the need to point out that altering structured data with a text-processing tool is suboptimal.

Comment: @arizona525 The naming of the file shouldn't matter, as long as the content is valid YAML (which is what is shown in the sample), especially if you provide the input on STDIN (adding `<` between the filter and the file name), so yq doesn't even see the file name at all. Btw, which implementation of `yq` did you try?

Comment: sorry I do have templating inside the yaml file so yq doesn't work. Perhaps I should look at awk as alternative

Comment: @arizona525 Again, text-processing tools do not handle the logical content of structured data, only its representation. And as there are many equally valid representations, the encoding will bite you at some point - unless you write a full parser. Thus, using one that is already written should be the way to go. As for which one to use, answers given here can only be as suitable to your problem as the question is representative. The sample input you have provided is valid YAML, and does not "have templating inside" it. Consider asking a question using sample data that contains such templates.

Answer (score 0):

With the provided input file, would you please try:

```
NEWID=5
sed -E '
/group1/,/group/{
    /(^|[[:blank:]])jerry:/{
        N; s/(myid:[[:blank:]]*)[[:digit:]]+/\1'"$NEWID"'/
    }
}' file.yaml.j2
```

Output:

```
brand:
    group1:
        jerry:
            myid: 5
        ben:
            myid: 2
    group2:
        jerry:
            myid: 3
        jane:
            myid: 4
```

- The condition `/group1/,/group/` limits the operation within `group1`.
- The regex `(^|[[:blank:]])jerry:/` prevents a partial match.

  - Considering the yaml structure, `^` will be superfluous.
  - If you are using `GNU` sed, `\b` (word boundary) will also work.
- It expects the `myid` line to follow just after the `jerry` line.

Please note the code above does not recogize the yaml syntax and will
easily break for altered (but valid) inputs.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't install a proper YAML tool, perhaps try Awk instead of `sed`. It has the obvious benefit that it's not a write-only language, and it has the concept of variables.

Here, we are assuming that the indentation level on `group1:` demarcates the section where you want to replace values, and the indentation level for `jerry:` demarcates it further.

```
awk -v value="NEWID" '/group1:/ { ind0 = $0; sub(/[^ \t].*/, "", ind0);
        print; next }
    ind0 && !($0 ~ "^" ind0 "[ \t]") { ind0 = "" }
    ind0 && /jerry:/ { ind1 = $0; sub(/[^ \t].*/, "", ind1);
        print; next }
    ind1 && !($0 ~ "^" ind1 "[ \t]") { ind1 = "" }
    ind1 && /myid:/ { sub(/myid: .*/, "myid: " value) }
    1' PATH_TO_FILE.yaml.j2 >PATH_TO_FILE.yaml.j2.NEW &&
mv PATH_TO_FILE.yaml.j2.NEW PATH_TO_FILE.yaml.j2
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/wYPOSG

If you have GNU Awk, you can enable in-place overwriting of the file with `-i inplace` and avoid the redirect and `mv` dance.